# About making ROC curve using result of training of random forest

Tags: r, random-forest, roc

I'am using caret package's train function to make random forest model like below.

```
control <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=10, repeats=5)
model <- train(BM~., data=cadrenal, method="rf", preProcess="scale", trControl=control)enter code here
```

BM is categorial row presenting B(benign) or M(malignant).
For this model, accuray is not so high as below.

```
Random Forest 

77 samples
 4 predictor
 2 classes: 'B', 'M' 

Pre-processing: scaled (4) 
Resampling: Cross-Validated (10 fold, repeated 5 times) 
Summary of sample sizes: 69, 69, 69, 70, 69, 70, ... 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  mtry  Accuracy   Kappa    
  2     0.7728571  0.4858102
  3     0.7650000  0.4708351
  4     0.7678571  0.4724770
```

Accuracy was used to select the optimal model using  the largest value.
The final value used for the model was `mtry = 2`.

Then, I tried to make ROC using this model as below.

```
cadrenal$malignancy <- factor(1*(cadrenal$BM == 'M'))
pre = predict(model, type='prob')
perf = prediction(pre[,2], cadrenal$malignancy)
pred = performance(perf, "tpr","fpr")
plot(pred,main="ROC Curve for Random Forest",col=2,lwd=2)
```

Then, in spite of low accuracy of the model, I got an ROC curve of with AUC is 1 .

Can anyone teach me what is wrong in my making ROC curve?

Comment: I suggest to split your dataset in a training and a testing set and to calculate AUC on the testing set. You should get more "realistic" values.

Comment: Thank you for your comment ! I guess you are right. But why can such things (i.e. low accuracy model shows ROC of AUC=1) happen?

Comment: One hypothesis is that your predictive tool is in overfitting, hence out-of-bag prediction error is not so good while in-sample prediction is high.

Comment: The reason for AUC=1 could be overfitting in train method